# Правильная организация сервисного слоя

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Всем доброго дня. есть следующие сущности:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public class UnitId {get;set;}
    ///прочие поля
}

public class OrderHistories
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public int StateId {get;set;}
    ///Прочие поля
    public int CreatorId {get;set;}
    public DateTime Created {get;set;}

}
```

Как в данном случае организовать "правильней/лучше/удобней" Service слой в приложении: вариантов то я вижу всего два: один в котором будет организована работа и с той и другой сущностью, либо же сделать IOrderService & IOrderHistoriesService? заранее спасибо

**update**

Вот такой у меня получился Service для работы с заявками. Если сделал не правильно, прошу меня поправить

```
public class OrderService: IOrderService
{
    private IRepository<Order> _orderRepository;
    private IRepository<HistoryOrder> _historyOrderRepository;

    public OrderService(IRepository<Order> orderRepository,
        IRepository<HistoryOrder> historyOrderRepository)
    {
        this._orderRepository = orderRepository;
        this._historyOrderRepository = historyOrderRepository;
    }

    ///Методы
}
```

Comment: В принципе все нормально у Вас.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сделайте все в одном IOrderService. Не вижу особого смысла разбивать сервисы по типам сущностей модели. В данном случае, Ваш IOrderService - это сервис для работы с заказами, так что вполне разумно, что он будет и работать с историей заказов (OrderHistories).

Answer (score 0):

> Ваш OrdersService: IOrdersService - ненужная абстракция. 
>   IRepository - это достаточная абстракция (на мой взгляд, тоже лишняя).

Не согласен с Вами. Что такое сервис? - это сердце нашего приложения, это наша бизнес логика. В данном случае, для работы сервиса нужна некая зависимость, источник данных, с которым сервис будет взаимодействовать. Вполне резонно ее внедрить в качестве зависимости через конструктор, т.к. источник данных может меняться (такое конечно происходит не часто, но вполне может быть).

Теперь об интерфейсах, в первую очередь они делают наше приложение гибким и позволяют подменить существующую реализацию иной, без "поломки" всего приложения.

Представим, что теперь у нашего сервиса в качестве источника данных должен быть XML файл, а не БД. В при существующем подходе, я могу предоставить некий репозиторий (реализует IRepository), который работает с XML и внедрить эту реализацию в текущий сервис и все будет работать.  При этом в самом сервисе ничего менять не нужно.

Аналогично с реализацией самого сервиса (IOrderService), можно предоставить совершенно иную реализацию, в противовес существующей.

Конечно, данная реализация - это самый примитивный вариант реализации сервиса, но он имеет право на жизнь и ничего такого "не правильного" в нем. Если ни каких иных требований со стороны бизнеса к сервису больше нет, то почему бы и нет...

Comment: Что такое сердце приложения? Что такое бизнес-логика? Как бизнес-логика вообще связана с сервисом? Пока для меня это только набор ничего не значащих слов. Теперь об интерфейсах. Во-вторую очередь они превращают наше приложение в мессиво интерфейсов, зачастую скрывая зависимости между компонентами (в том числе циклические), внутри DI-контейнеров.

Comment: По поводу остальных трёх параграфов - я вижу только какие-то фантазии о том, что что-то может измениться, и попытку спроектировать вундервафлю, сложность которой в разы превосходит сложность приложения. Разделяйте приложение не горизонтально на слои, а на вертикально, на слабо связанные небольшие компоненты, которые соответствуют бизнес-функционалу и решаемым проблемам.

Answer (score -1):

> есть следующие сущности

Это не сущности, это записи или, если угодно, дата контракты, сущности отличаются наличием поведения и таймлайна.

Ваш `OrdersService: IOrdersService` - ненужная абстракция. `IRepository<T>` - это достаточная абстракция (на мой взгляд, тоже лишняя).

Для просветления читать про [Domain Driven Design](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5):

- [Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity In The Heart Of Software by Eric Evans](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321125215) - есть перевод на русский
- [Implementing Domain Driven Design by Vaughn Vernon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321834577)
- Video: [8 lines of code by Greg Young](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/8-lines-code-refactoring) - следует посмотреть, Greg Young рассказывает про "сервисы", зачем они нужны, и как их делать правильно
- Video: [Greg Young - CQRS and Event Sourcing - Code on the Beach 2014](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHGkaShoyNs) - вот в ходе подобных лекций Greg Young рассказывает про DDD в том числе

Comment: а не могли бы Вы добавить свой ответ примером как бы Вы это сделали? заранее спасибо

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, что от меня хочется, и что в оригинальном сообщение понимается под "сервисным слоем". Проблема в том, что это очень расплывчатая формулировка, и на основании этой нечеткой формулировки идёт попытка построить архитектуру, при этом без ответов на вопросы - с какими намерениями она создается, и какие проблемы она решает.

Comment: необходимо приложение в котором можно будет формировать некие "заявки" в конкретном случае на приобретение "комплектующих", полазил по инету, почитал рекомендуют делать слабосвязанные приложения: сделал проект в котором есть решение где есть классы описывающие предметную область(в моем понимании сущность), в этом же проекте есть следующие классы/интерфейсы IRepository класс его реализующий и аналогично с контекстом. следующий проект работает с интерфейсом IRepository<T>. а абстракция IOrderService реализует конкретные действия с данными, получить список, вставить и т.п.

Comment: @PavelHritonenko если вы не понимаете, что в оригинальном сообщении подразумевается под "сервисным слоем" - то как вы можете уверждать что он не нужен? Если вы не отвечаете на вопрос, а просто высказываете общее мнение о коде топикастера  - не постите это как ответ. Обойдитесь комментарием.

Comment: @PashaPash я вижу, что топик-стартер сам не понимает, что такое сервисный слой, и чего он хочет, и пытается собрать своё приложение из кусков абстрактных терминов из интернета. Я всего лишь хочу обратить внимание на то, что добавлять что либо в приложение нужно с намерениями, чтобы решить существующую проблему, а не усложнять его ненужными абстракциями и "сервисами".

Comment: @PavelHritonenko ну так создайте чат и доносите там до топикастера мысли. возьмите его под крыло, и научите TDD постить тут ответы-не ответы с пачкой ссылок на часовые лекции - контрпродуктивно. потому что это тоже самое, что сказать "твой код - фигня, иди учись год, потом приходи задавать сюда вопросы". причем даже не глядя на сам код.

Comment: @Bald56rus ну так и начните писать это приложение. Определите функционал, который вам нужен и пишите. Не пытайтесь тащить вообще все паттерны из интернета. Ни один "бизнес-человек" вам никогда не скажет ничего ни про репозиторий, ни про "сервисный слой". Будет дублирование кода - добавите репозитории, или сделаете один репозиторий на любые свои нужды. Выделение "сервисного слоя" и репозиториев вам не поможет выделить логику, оно только запутает. Этот подход ХУЖЕ, даже чем вызов методов EF-контекста из хэндлеров событий.

Comment: @PashaPash ну конечно, направлять в тупиковую сторону и помечать это как "ответ" - очень полезно для тех, кто наткнется на это обсуждение.

Comment: @PavelHritonenko именно написанием приложения я и занимаюсь, под "сервисным слоем" я подразумеваю следующее: это код который возвращает данные(Order, IEnumerable<Order>) и т.д. для UI в ходе написания вот возник вопрос и я его создал.но наверно неверно сформулировал название. совсем бездумно тащить ничего не пытаюсь поэтому такие вопросы и возникают.

Comment: Уважаемые участники, для активных обсуждений используйте чат, а не комментарии.

Comment: @Bald56rus "это код который возвращает данные(Order, IEnumerable<Order>" - давайте посмотрим на IRepository<T> - не он ли это, зачем ещё одна абстракция? Более того, IDbSet<T> в EF занимается тем же самым.